# How to remove quotes and commas from LIST Python?

Tags: python

i have This List:

['https://test.com/test.jpg', 'https://test.com/test.jpg']

I need to send in this form:

https://test.com/test.jpg https://test.com/test.jpg

I use this code:

```
await client.send_message(channel, str(text) + str(", ".join( repr(e) for e in image )))
```

I tried to do so, but it did not work for me.

```
[i.replace('"', '') for i in image]
```

What else can you try?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.join`

```
s = ['https://test.com/test.jpg', 'https://test.com/test.jpg']
print(" ".join(s))
```

**Output:**

```
https://test.com/test.jpg https://test.com/test.jpg
```